# Initialize useState value inside useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a value `k` to be initialized only once using the useState hook, and I have created the useEffect hook to be triggered only once after the component mounts. The useEffect callback will create an intersection observer to update the state of `k` when desired, thus updating the component and calling the useState initialization again. How do I keep the value of `k` from reset during updates? In other words, is there any way to put the useState initialization inside the `useEffect(() =>{},[])` hook?

here is my code example. Just for illustration purposes.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Data = Array.from(Array(1000).keys());

const Content = (props) =>{
  console.log("from beginning")
  const [totalNumberOfEntries, setTotalNumberOfEntries] = useState(100);

    useEffect(() => {


      let observer = new IntersectionObserver(loadMoreData);
    
      observer.observe(document.getElementById("bottom"));


    
      function loadMoreData(entries, observer){
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if(entry.isIntersecting === true){
    
            setTotalNumberOfEntries(totalNumberOfEntries + 100);
        
          }
      })};
      return ()=>{
        observer.disconnect();
      }
  
    },[])

  return(
    <>
      {
        Array.from({length: totalNumberOfEntries}, (v, i) => i).map(
          (i) => (<div>{props.data[i]}</div>)
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
function App() {

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Content data = {Data}/>
      </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

The "bottom" element is the element below the "root" element.

Comment: First, you won't be able to put the useState initialization inside the useEffect hook; see the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Second, I think you're misunderstanding how useState works, the value of `k` won't "reset" during subsequent renders, that's the whole purpose of hooking into state. Showing some code that you've tried would go a long way here.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily update the value of **useState** inside useEffect by using **setState**

```
    const a = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   setState(0); // this will set state to zero
},[])

return(
<div>abc</div>
)
}
```